# AccessVBAで、フォームをダイアログで開いているはずが処理が流れてしまう

Tags: vba, ms-access, form

お世話になります。

AccessのVBAで、フォームをダイアログで(そこでブロックして)表示しようとしているのですが、どうやってもそのまま処理が流れてしまいます。

行っていることは、
プロパティでは
・ポップアップ = はい
・作業ウィンドウ固定 = はい

実際にコードで表示する際には、
        DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", , , , , acDialog
と　記述しています。

これだけの設定でできるはずなのですが、他に何か原因がありますでしょうか。

下記にその部分コードを記述します。

```
For cnt = 0 To 3
    MsgBox "" & cnt & "階です。"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", , , , , acDialog

    MsgBox "a"
Next
```

『○階です』の部分が出てから『a』が、F_Floorの終了を待たずに出てしまいます。

Accessのバージョンは2010です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「そのまま処理が流れてしまいます」to

Comment: 「そのまま処理が流れてしまいます」というのは、どこかの入力待ちをするようなコードを書かれたという事でしょうか。　作られたコードを質問に追加してください。

Comment: すみません、質問の内容を追加しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoCmd.OpenForm は、第１引数のフォーム名以外は省略可能です。そのため、第２引数以降は引数名を明記しなくてはなりません。

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", , , , , acDialog
```

で、WindowModeがacDialogになることを期待したのでしょうが、acDialogをどの引数として扱うかシステムが判断できないので機能しないのです。

上に示したコードの行を、以下のように修正してみてください。

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", WindowMode:= acDialog
```

Comment: ご返答が遅れ、大変申し訳ありませんでした。お教えいただいた方法でうまくいきました。本当に遅れてすみませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Comment: VBAでの引数は、（名前指定でない場合）位置指定で判断されるので、そのコードは同じ意味になるはずですが。少なくとも2007で試して同じ結果なので、引数の指定方法が原因だとは思えないのですが

Comment: OpenFormの場合、第1引数は必須ですが、それ以降の引数は省略可能です。そのため、DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", , , , , acDialog、DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", , , ,  acDialog、DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor" , , , acDialog、DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor" , , acDialog、DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor",  acDialogというバリエーションが可能です（省略された引数の数でacDialogの出てくる場所が変わります）。だからacDialogだけではシステムが判断できないのです。引数が省略可能ということは、その後の引数の位置がずれる可能性があるということですので、位置指定では決してありません。すべての引数が省略されることなく書かれていた場合に限り、位置指定で判断されるのです。

Comment: 少なくとも2007までのVBAでは、名前付き引数を使わない場合は位置指定であり、その場合は（指定する引数の前の）カンマは省略できません。DoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", acDialogはDoCmd.OpenForm "F_Floor", view:=acDialogと同じはずです